# Can't compress a folder in %temp% to a .zip file after creating a .txt file in it - "File in use by another process"

Tags: c#, windows

I'm creating an app for Windows in C# that extracts .zip file into the %temp% folder and shows you the contents and lets you edit them. After you finish editing the files, you can save the file again - the app deletes the original .zip and compresses the folder into the same file (that was deleted) so that it looks like it was replaced.

I've tried creating a new empty .zip file through the app and saving it. That worked. Then I also tried creating a folder in it and saving it. That also worked, but when I create a new .txt file, then it gives me the "file in use" error. This error doesn't occur when I edit a .txt file that already was in the .zip archive and save it.

```
//.txt file creation into the dir where the .zip file was extracted
System.IO.File.Create(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "UltraDocs\\" + rnd + "\\" + listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem) + "\\" + toolStripTextBox3.Text + ".txt");
System.IO.File.SetAttributes(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "UltraDocs\\" + rnd + "\\" + listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem) + "\\" + toolStripTextBox3.Text + ".txt", ~System.IO.FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
//Compression
System.IO.File.Delete(filedia.FileName);
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "UltraDocs\\" + rnd, filedia.FileName);
//This line gives me a "*.txt is currently in use by another process" error
```

Any ideas what might be causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Use `using`- paradigma for file creation - if you leave it filehandle should be released - you still have an open handle on it somewhere

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thank you so much. It worked!

Comment: Consider posting the fixed code as answer then - you can accept it as self answer in  ~48hours